# Why does p-value have to be defined as 'at least as extreme' as the test statistic rather than just the probability that T= t?

Tags: t-test, p-value

Say I am using a t statistic, the (two-tailed-t test) p-value as i understand is given as pr(t$\geq$|t| |null is true), why cant it be that pr(t=t|null) or at least some small relative frequency in an infinitesimal distance around t, such as f(t)dt ?

Comment: It's a good question and, as you might imagine, occurs in many contexts, so you can find various answers (in passing) in quite a few threads.  The duplicate is one with many answers and several of them address this question head-on.